# Magento image not showing on frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I have a website that I maintain, and I happened to visit a product that although in the admin I can see that I have 7 photos of the product in the front end I can only see 6 of them. Strangely enough I also noticed that if I right click on "Inspect" I found that the image is "pulled" properly and I if I copy the link and enter it to the browser it's displayed properly. 
Any idea what is causing it?

**EDIT:** This is a snapshot of the admin seciton. I can't see the image with sort order 1 in the frontend.

[image]

Comment: Put snap of product images list from admin panel

Comment: please check `Exclude` checkbox is not checked after any image

Comment: well.. it's not. I thought it visible through the snapshop  :-\

Comment: I also searched in the server and the photo is there in /media/catalog/product. I downloaded the image and uploaded it again in Magento but no luck. Is there any possibility that it's the images fault ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it. Seems like Magento is VERY strict with the naming convention of the images. My image was named 5206987712652-2.jpg  but it is necessary that it needs the underscore instead, like 5206987712652_2.jpg.